# Assume any role based on condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, assume-role

I want to have an IAM user that have a permission to assume any role that have access to any S3 bucket.
I have the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently my IAM user can assume any role, how can I limit the user so it can assume only the roles that have read/write access to any S3 bucket in any region

Comment: That is not possible. You need to know which roles you want to allow the assume into, e.g. based on their name. Fundamentally IAM cannot even answer the question "what can principal XYZ do?" nor "what principals can do XYZ", it can only answer "can X do Y to resource Z with the current request context?".

Comment: Is it possible to validate a specific permissions myself?
for example:
can I create an api request to validate if IAM role X has access to S3?

Comment: No, as I said: IAM can only tell if an action A by Principal P on resource R is allowed. In particular that involves the specific resource and all the potentially relevant metadata, e.g. tags, the request context, e.g. time, IP, etc. And for almost all actions there is no dry-run option for that action but the only way to know if it is allowed is to actual perform that action. Want to know if you can delete an object? Try deleting it - if you are allowed it will be deleted, if you are not allowed you will get an error.

Comment: And for S3 in particular you might additionally have resource policies playing into all of this and the principal and it's attached policies do not even determine all the buckets it might be able to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is by [tagging the respective roles](https://go.aws/3Yn4F1S), e.g. with the Key `S3Access` set to `True`, and then use a policy using the tag as a condition:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AssumeTaggedRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"iam:ResourceTag/S3Access": "True"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To learn more, check out [Controlling access to and for IAM users and roles using tags](https://go.aws/459ztp0) in the AWS IAM user guide.